# Followed install-from-package to the letter, but get error: FATAL - password authentication failed for user "ckan_default"

Tags: linux, installation, package

Followed https://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-package.html quite literally on a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS. In section 4.2 after `sudo ckan db init` I get FATAL - password authentication failed for user "ckan_default".

Something must be wrong/missing on that page... Probably something very obvious (except to a first time user..?)